# MySQL Global Setting lost on reboot of OSX

Tags: mysql, macos, global, setting

I have to work around some strict setting that OSX requires for MySQL locally.

To do this, I have to:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='MYSQL40';
```

When I reboot the machine, this change is lost. It's not a big deal, but I'd love to understand why this change isn't sticking and what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried both via mysql cli and phpmyadmin, both as root.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the setting was in my.cnf which was located in /usr/local/mysql-5.6.23-osx10.8-x86_64

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

The above setting was at the bottom of the file. It forces strict for tables which was causing problems with Laravel 5 locally.

I set it to

```
sql_mode=MYSQL40
```

and restarted mysql with

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
```

So far, so good.